# Make text displayed in toast selectable

Tags: android, toast

I want the text displayed in a Toast message to be selectable (as in copy and pastable). Is this possible? I know it's possible to create a custom Toast message and set the TextView in the layout to be selectable, but that has not been working so far for me.

Comment: you should use `dialogfragment` for this. All toast have fixed duration after which it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a toast is to display a quick information to the user. The user cannot interact with toasts. Follow suku's suggestion, create a dialogfragment with a textview and make the textview selectable.